# Как записать в массив типа char цифры (не символы), не используя нажатия enter?

Tags: c

При использовании `scanf` нужно нажимать <kbd>Enter</kbd>, функции `getch()` или `getchar()` считывают символ, а мне нужны цифры, а не символы.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы преобразовать введённый символ в число, можно использовать тот факт, что цифры в таблице символов идут последовательно без пропусков в порядке возрастания. Примерно так:

```
char c = getch();
if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
    char i = (char)(c - '0');
else
    printf("Табе ж сказали, цифИрки вводи!\n");
```

Comment: int i = (int)(c - '0'); тут идет преобразование типа, а у меня элементы массива должны быть типа char

Comment: @Jessy Да какая разница-то? Обновил ответ.

Comment: Для лучшего понимания добавлю, что `char` - это обычный целочисленный тип. Просто он самый маленький (обычно - 8 бит) и достаточен для представления символов, если писать по английски. Поэтому переменными этого типа представляются строки. (Язык C разрабатывался американцами и они, видимо, поначалу не особо беспокоились об интернационализации. Также C довольно либерален в части преобразования типов. Поэтому можно написать даже так: `char i = c - '0';`. На самом деле, с учетом целочисленного расширения, это будет интерпретироваться как `char i = (char)((int)c - (int)'0');`

Comment: @KonstantinLes Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Для реализации подобных задач полезно иметь понимание о типе `char` и о преобразованиях целых типов в C.

`char` - это обычный целочисленный тип. Просто он самый маленький (обычно - 8 бит) и достаточен для представления символов, если писать по английски. Поэтому переменными этого типа представляются строки. (Язык C разрабатывался американцами и они, видимо, поначалу не особо беспокоились об интернационализации.)
Есть еще одно отличие, которое не мешает знать. Все целочисленные типы, кроме `char` являются знаковыми, если явно не указано иное. Например:

```
int == signed int
```

При объявлении переменной целого типа без знака необходимо задать спецификатор `unsigned`, например:

```
unsigned long l;
```

Тип данных `char` без спецификатора может быть и знаковым и беззнаковым. Стандартом не предусмотрено однозначное поведение - решение принимает разработчик компилятора.
Пока переменные типа `char` используются для представления символов, знаковые они или нет - не имеет значения. Если такие переменные применяются в арифметических выражениях, это уже может иметь значение.
Поэтому, если необходимо гарантировать наличие или отсутствие знака у типа `char`, необходимо явно это указывать:

```
signed char ИЛИ unsigned char
```

Также C довольно либерален в части преобразования типов. Поэтому можно написать так:

```
char i = c - '0';
```

На самом деле, с учетом целочисленного расширения, это будет интерпретироваться как

```
char i = (char)((int)c - (int)'0');
```

Comment: И все же, на практике я не припомню ни одной системы , в которой `char` был бы беззнаковым.

Comment: @avp После того, как мне это стало известно, всегда задаю явно. Поэтому, честно говоря, даже и не знаю, как это сделано в использованных мною компиляторах. Если мне не изменяет память, обычно этот параметр задается в опциях. Но, наверное, логично чтобы по умолчанию `char` был знаковым.